Acceptable resistance between hot (mains) and ground (earth)?
A DIY project I'm working on uses electronics embedded in concrete, including 110V AC heating elements. As I was verifying my wiring before testing the device I was surprised to discover conductivity on the order of ~1MΩ+ between my hot and ground (and also neutral and ground).
Concrete conducts electricity! TIL.
From a standards and safety perspective, what's an acceptable amount of resistance/current to allow between hot and ground?

I guess the way I worded it is technically wrong. Resistance of about 1MΩ, conductivity of about 1μS.

you can edit the question

"Concrete conducts electricity!" - yes - google "Ufer ground".

Concrete is a sponge.  It will absorb moisture from its surroundings and the absorbed water will be even more conductive.

I'd be really worried about electrolytic activity even if the leakage current is acceptable. Liquid concrete is a dangerously strong caustic (similar pH to drain cleaner) and I'm sure a bunch of ions are left hanging around waiting for some moisture. AFAIK, SOP is to use thick PVC conduits.

@SottoVoce To stop the spread of misinformation, water is only a conductor if it has ions in it.
